# Selenium: ¿Por qué mi programa python no puede abrir una ventana después de clickear un botón?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome, depuración

He creado un simple programa python que abre [esta página](https://opensea.io/) con `chromedriver.exe`, luego clickea en el ícono de la billetera ubicado en la esquina superior derecha de esa página, para luego clickear en el botón de MetaMask wallet, aquí está el código:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default") #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.

initial_page = driver.current_window_handle  #make the previous page the current one
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button')
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
#time.sleep(1)
wallet_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='WalletSidebar--body']//li")
for i in wallet_options:
    if "MetaMask" in i.get_attribute('innerText'): #find the MetaMask wallet button
        i.click() #click the MetaMask wallet button
```

El problema que noté cuando probaba este código fue que después de clickear en el botón Metamask wallet de manera automatizada, la esperada ventana `Metamask Notification` nunca fue desplegada, y la ventana actual siguió cargando ese botón eternamente como se muestra a continuación:

[image: problempreview1]

Sin embargo, **sí yo como usuario clickease el mismo botón de MetaMask wallet** usando el mismo `chromedriver.exe`, la ventana `Metamask Notification` inmediatamente se desplegaría como se esperaba, para luego solicitar mi contraseña y proceder a conectar esa wallet a este sitio web, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: expected_result1]

Inclusive revisé sí había otra ventana oculta después de presionar el botón de MetaMask wallet button (con el programa automatizado) usando las siguientes líneas, pero no hubo nada:

```py
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle != initial_page:
        login_page = handle
        driver.switch_to.window(login_page)
```

Estoy muy confundido, ¿por qué ese botón sí funciona cuando yo como usuario lo presiono manualmente, pero cuando lo hace el programa se queda haciendo buffering? Apreciaría muchísimo sí alguien puede explicarme por qué sucede esto y sí también puede asistirme en la mejora del código mismo?

Comment: La respuesta a porqué no te `deja` automatizarlo es obvia, pero la verdadera pregunta es: ¿ A cuento de qué viene ese empecinamiento en `automatizar` el acceso al `login` de `MetaMask`? Alguien podría pensar que lo que quieres es `hackear` cuentas...

Comment: De hecho, tengo pensado hacer un proyecto open-source para subir NFTs de manera masiva a OpenSea, dado que una persona en general es muy propensa a agotarse haciéndolo o a equivocarse (para colecciones de más de 100 NFTs en adelante), y lo quiero hacer de tal forma que se omita el paso de contraseñas y llaves privadas, ahora, ¿puedes explicarme la respuesta? @FranciscoJavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo descubrí simplemente tenía que agregar la ruta de la extensión (la cual [debe estar comprimida](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-export-an-installed-extension-chrome/) como un archivo `.crx`) como argumento a las `Options()` de Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default") #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
extension_path = r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn\10.8.1_0.crx' #ruta de la extensión comprimida en un archivo .crx
opt.add_extension(extension_path) #añadir la ruta como argumento

s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.

initial_page = driver.current_window_handle  #make the previous page the current one
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button')
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
#time.sleep(1)
wallet_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='WalletSidebar--body']//li")
for i in wallet_options:
    if "MetaMask" in i.get_attribute('innerText'): #find the MetaMask wallet button
        i.click() #click the MetaMask wallet button
```

Así pues, al compilar el código mejorado, genera la siguiente salida:

[image: solution1]

Lo que sí noté es que este programa termina abriendo una pestaña y una ventana del chromedriver para acceder a la wallet de Metamask (es decir, hacen lo mismo).

Sí alguien puede decirme **cómo evitar que la pestaña de MetaMask no se abra como se muestra en la imagen**, por favor háganmelo saber.